# Tengo un problema con una peticion por ajax a mi base de datos en Laravel 5.6

Tags: ajax, laravel

Acabo de realizar una petición de datos por ajax a mi base de datos, pero me responde lo siguiente:

> Failed to load http://localhost:8000/almacen/proveedor/1: Redirect
>   from 'http://localhost:8000/almacen/proveedor/1' to
>   'http://localhost:8000/login' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: bienvenido, para que podamos ayudarte mejor te aconsejo agregar a tu pregunta el codigo que implementaste para llegar a ese error. por otro lado parece que te esta queriendo redireccionar al login cuando haces la peticion, como si no estuvieras logueado.

Comment: Estoy logueado a la aplicación y trato de conseguir datos por ajax después del evento onclick de un de los botones de la vista.